# How to use datetime picker as editortemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui, mvc-editor-templates

How can i use datetime picker in my mvc view .

EditorTemplate : Datetime.cshtml

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"):"", new { @class = "datefield" })

Model : 
[Required]
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }.

Also jquery.ui.all.css is under my solution content>themes>base
```

Here is the partial view where the datepicker is needed .

```
@model PersonalDetails`
```

`
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
                
                    
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { @placeholder = "Date Of Birth", @class = "datefield" ,@type="text" })
                
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)

```
Here the date field is coming in the format specified in the Datetime editor template. But the calendor image is not coming.
```

Comment: What is wrong with using [jQuery UI datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: Did you try their sample code ? What is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: bootstrap does not have a datepicker. there are other people who wrote bootstrap datepickers. [Let me google that for you](https://www.google.com/#pws=0&q=bootstrap+datepicker+)

Comment: @Shyju : I am tried implementing Jquery UI datePicker, The problem i am facing is the calendar image is not getting displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have editor set up for jQuery datepicker:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { @placeholder = "Date Of Birth", @class = "datefield", @type="text" })
```

Check if your JS code has working properly by browser debugging, your datepicker code should looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datefield").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        // other datepicker settings here as you want
    });
});
</script>
```

Then make sure jQuery UI CSS file has included either inside `Layout.cshtml` or inside head tag on your page, at this step your calendar image should be shown besides date editor:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" type="text/css">
<script src="~/Scripts/jQuery-[version].js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="~/Scripts/jQuery-ui-[version].js" type="text/javascript">
```

To simplify those script and style declarations, I suggest you learning MVC styles/scripts bundling.

Any suggestions welcome.